# Notepad++ can I see all marked words on edge of window?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++. I'd like to see all highlighted marked words in my document at a glance. Is there a way get an icon or indicator to display on the edge of the window? I could then see where in the whole document the marked words show up?

Thank you...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: Yes, use the search, then the Mark tab. Check the `bookmark line` option to mark all lines for what you're trying to find. This bookmark appears on the left-hand side of the document where the line numbers appear.

Comment: I did see that feature but I still have to scroll through the entire document looking to see where all the book marks are. I've seen in the past on other editors, a small mark is make along the right edge so you can scroll up or down to that mark and get to the search word. Bookmark does everything but that as far as I can tell.